# multiple markers are not showing on map in react Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

i am trying to show multiple markers on map in but i the markers are not showing and there's no error so i am unable to solve it,so Basically i am trying to get the coordinates from the state and trying to show multiple markers.Since i am new to react Native i might be doing something stupidly wrong.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps'


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    this.state = {
      markers: [{
        title: 'hi',
        coordinates: {
          latitude: 3.148561,
          longitude: 101.652778
        },
      },
      {
        title: 'hello',
        coordinates: {
          latitude: 3.149771,
          longitude: 101.655449
        },

      },
      {
        title: 'hey',
        coordinate: {
          latitude: 33.5336684,
          longitude: 131.3420892
        },

      },
      {
        title: 'heyThere',
        coordinate: {
          latitude: 24.8345714,
          longitude: 67.3589759
        }
      }
      ]
    }
    return (

      <MapView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        showsUserLocation={true}

      >
        {this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => (
          <MapView.Marker key={index}
            coordinate={marker.coordinates}
            title={marker.title}
          />
        ))}
      </MapView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
this.state = {
      markers: [{
        title: 'hi',
        coordinates: {
          latitude: 3.148561,
          longitude: 101.652778
        },
      },
    ...
```

to the constructor or just keep it in the class (Remove from the `render` function).

There are typos in markers array. Set the same key for all elements in the markers array (Currently you have `coordinates` and `coordinate`).

Also try to change the style of the MapView to { width: '100%', height: '100%' } if it doesn't render the MapView.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. I think your all marker are overlapped on each other or you pass wrong latitude or longitude. Please check your marker array something like this.

```
 markers: [
        {
          coordinates: {
            latitude: 45.524548,
            longitude: -122.6749817,
          },
          title: "Best Place",
          description: "This is the best place in Portland",
          image: Images[0],
        },
        {
          coordinates: {
            latitude: 45.524698,
            longitude: -122.6655507,
          },
          title: "Second Best Place",
          description: "This is the second best place in Portland",
          image: Images[1],
        },
        {
          coordinates: {
            latitude: 45.5230786,
            longitude: -122.6701034,
          },
          title: "Third Best Place",
          description: "This is the third best place in Portland",
          image: Images[2],
        },
        {
          coordinates: {
            latitude: 45.521016,
            longitude: -122.6561917,
          },
          title: "Fourth Best Place",
          description: "This is the fourth best place in Portland",
          image: Images[3],
        },
      ]
```